# I don't know how to get data from fetch correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux, fetch

I have a Users class where I want to get data from the server for later writing it to state and passing data from state to the child component

```
export default class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: this.getUsers(),
    };
  }

  getUsers = async () => {
    await return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users`, {
      method: 'POST',
      accept: 'application/json'
    }).then(res => {
      if(res.ok) {
        res.json();
      }
    })
  }
}
```

this is what the console shows me when I output data about `this.state.users`

[image]

I tried to look for similar situations, but I didn't find anything worthwhile, so I ask for help here. I would be grateful for any advice or help. I'm only learning asynchrony in js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use async await, you don't have to pass callback function, just `await` the promises and update the state incase of successful response.

```
getUsers = async () => {
    try {
       const response =  await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users`, {
         method: 'POST',
         accept: 'application/json'
       });

       const users = await response.json();

       this.setState({ users });

     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
 }
```

and instead of calling `getUsers` function from the constructor, use `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
}
```

and your state should be initially null or an empty array

```
this.state = {
  users: []
};
```

Comment: thank you for your help, you very well explained and gave a solution to my problem.

Comment: ```this.getUsers();``` inside ```componentDidMount``` will throw unhandled exception, if the request fails.

Comment: @JuniusL. isn't try-catch block inside `getUsers` function handling the exception? I have just added the console.log statement but OP could create a new state variable that would be updated, from the `catch` block, in case of an error.

Answer (score 1):

Add [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and call getUsers and set state.

```
this.state = {
  users: [],
};

getUsers = async () => {
  return await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users`, {
    method: 'POST',
    accept: 'application/json'
  }).then(response => response.json())
   .then(res => { this.seState({ users: res })})
   .catch(e => { console.log(e)})
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getUsers()
    .catch(e => console.log(e)
}
```